# Regression trees with geepack package

Tags: panel-data, cart, rpart, geepack

I can’t run regression trees without geeglm. I have longitudinal data so rpart wouldn’t work. Is there a way to get regression trees with geeglm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any decision tree based on `geeglm`. However, you can use the `glmtree()` function from the `partykit` package and specify the `cluster=` argument. This essentially corresponds to using `geeglm()` with an independence working model and a clustered covariance matrix estimate.

Alternatively, you can use `glmertree()` from the package `glmertree` which combines the `glmer()` function from `lme4` for estimating the random effects and `glmtree()` from `partykit` to estimate the tree structure. For more details see: Fokkema *et al.* (2018). "Detecting Treatment-Subgroup Interactions in Clustered Data with Generalized Linear Mixed-Effects Model Trees." *Behavior Research Methods*, **50**(5), 2016-2034. [doi:10.3758/s13428-017-0971-x](https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-017-0971-x)